# Azure B2C OTP Expiration During MFA and Password Reset

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Is there a way to increase the expiration time of OTP codes delivered via email during MFA and password reset? My users are getting the email later than 8 minutes and by the time they use the code, it is expired. What is the actual default? Is there a way to leverage the OTP technical profile described here [Define a OTP technical profile in an Azure AD B2C custom policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/one-time-password-technical-profile) ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the default expiration time is dependent on the method you're using to send them to code.

As far as I can tell from the documentation, the most customizable method for sending the OTP is using the OTP protocol provider you linked in your question.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/one-time-password-technical-profile

This protocol provider has a specific metadata item you can set for the expiration time (CodeExpirationInSeconds). It's min is 60, it's max is 1200 and it's default is 600.

If you need more fine grained control over the expiration time of the code, I would use this protocol provider to do it.

Comment: How do I use this OTP technical profile in custom policy in  a password reset journey?

Comment: The OTP technical profile only works with [custom email](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/custom-email-verifcation-displaycontrol) or [custom SMS](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/custom-sms-displaycontrol) providers. The Azure MFA (phonefactor technical profile) service sends SMS otp codes valid for 3mins. The SSPR technical profile sends email otp codes valid for 5min.

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT Thank you so much. So, as far as a password reset journey, there is no way to modify the validity period of the OTP code?

Comment: Not without using the links in my comment.